# Flowtype: Subtype that makes optional property required

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Given the following Flow type alias (note that `payload` is an optional property):

```
type Action = { type: string, payload?: any }
```

How would I create a subtype of Action where `payload` is **not** optional anymore?

Generics doesn't get me anywhere because that works only on the type of `payload` itself, not the fact that it's optional. Preferably I'd like to be able to simply do this:

```
type MoreSpecificAction extends Action = { payload: any }
```

Working with a specific type where I know `payload` is not optional would allow me to avoid a lot of undefined checks. As a bonus I could make the type more specific too, but I can already achieve that using generics.

#### Solution

As explained in the accepted answer by Lewis, the solution is to use the spread operator along with `$Exact<Action>`. However, babel-eslint currently does not support this syntax, but there's a workaround using comments. Here's my final solution:

```
type LoadAttendeesAction = {
  payload: Array<Attendee>,
  /* :: ...$Exact<Action> */
};
```

One caveat is that `Action` will need to be in scope, but ESLint won't consider it being used, so you may need:

```
// eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well-timed. I just asked about this exact thing here:  https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3534

You can do what you want using this:

```
type Action = {
  type: string,
  payload?: any
}

type MoreSpecificAction = {
  payload: any,
  ...$Exact<Action>
}
```

Just beware that currently, it seems like "downcasting" in this case will not report an error when it should (as of Flow 0.44.1):

```
const y: Action = {
  type: 'ACTION'
};

(y: MyAction);
```

But other than that, you will be able to write your action creators and reducers using `MoreSpecificAction` as defined above.

Comment: Awesome. It appears there's an outstanding issue with the spread syntax in babel-eslint, but there's a workaround using comments: https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/443#issuecomment-293852225

By the way, is it correct to not have an import for `$Exact`? It seems to work but doesn't feel right.

Comment: Yeah that's correct, $Exact is a global utility type.